# Is it possible to use rtsp without a server?

Tags: java, android, rtsp

Can I for example stream video from one android device to another without translation to server?
Just like video call
If there is any library to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is any good RTSP sever in java. http://www.live555.com/ is a good option for c/c++. For personal use it is possible to use VLC in command line.